# Jenkins Pipeline bat multiple lines

Tags: batch-file, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

According to [the docs](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-durable-task-step/#bat-windows-batch-script), one can have multiple lines in the `script` paramater of `bat`.

However, I've tried the following in my stage steps and only the first line gets executed.

Declarative pipeline:

```groovy
...
bat """
    c:\\path\\to\\conda activate my_env
    cd c:\\path\\to\\scripts
    python myscript.py ${some_arg}
"""
...
```

Scripted pipeline:

```groovy
...
bat(
    returnStdout: true, 
    script: """
        c:\\path\\to\\conda activate my_env
        cd c:\\path\\to\\scripts
        python myscript.py ${some_arg}
    """
)
...
```

What do I need to do to get all the lines to execute sequentially?

PS
I know I can chain the commands into a single line with "&" but that quickly becomes unreadable with lots of commands.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You [need](https://ss64.com/nt/call.html) to add the keyword `call`, whereever you are invoking Windows batch scripts (`.bat` or `.cmd`), else the executed batch file won't return control. E.g.:

```groovy
...
bat """
    call c:\\path\\to\\conda activate my_env
    cd c:\\path\\to\\scripts
    call python myscript.py ${some_arg}
"""
...
```

Comment: Seems it was my ignorance of bat files that was the problem. Thank you.

Comment: can you please rate the answer also :)

Comment: Why the need to add `call`?

Comment: Because that's how Windows batch files work.